# Microsoft Excel Sorting?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel file with:

`name , email , phonenumber of the student and decimal numbers as marks`

How do I sort the marks so that I get the highest score and corresponding name and other data of the corresponding student in descending order?

I have used the **Rank** function but I figured that it is not what I want.

Please help, its urgent.
Any help is great.

Comment: Just use the built-in sorting method

Comment: Why do you need function? Have a look here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Sort-data-in-a-range-or-table-62d0b95d-2a90-4610-a6ae-2e545c4a4654?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Comment: @Dave i want to learn it so that if this kind of situation comes again i dont have to empty my pocket again and again... if you know the answer to this question then kindly tell .

Comment: @RonRosenfeld i used built in sort but that sorts only the marks column and the remaining columns are not changing ,,, the case becomes is like assigning low marks to some other student. i want to sort the marks and the corresponding other data of the student too..

Comment: @BAYMAX If you select only a **single** cell in a contiguous table, or if you select the entire table before sorting, all the columns should sort together.

Comment: @RonRosenfield i did that but it sorts some other columns like rollno or phone number or serial number.

Comment: @BAYMAX Please post an example (with sensitive information removed) that demonstrates the problem.  If some of the entries are populated using formulas, that can sometimes cause an issue, depending on the formula and where they are pulling data.  But ordinarily, there should be no issue.

Comment: You're basically asking for a "report". Get the top person and then show the rest in student order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select all the *Data Field* - *Rows & Columns* (like Name, Roll No. & Marks) you want to arrange in a *Order*.
2. Right-click on the Selected Field.
3. Then go-to *Sort* → *Custom Sort* (Follow the attached Images)

   [image: Right menu selection]
4. Then in *Column Sort by* field select *Marks column*, in *Sort On* select *Values* and in *Order* field select *Largest to Smallest* (as you want to arrange Student Marks in Descending order).

   [image: Sort popup window selection]
5. Then click on *OK*
6. Now you can see Marks and its corresponding fields are arranged in Descending order.
7. Done!

Comment: Thank you , that solves my problem ..Also to other users who helped.